# How to export a Wordpress blog with no export function?

Tags: import

So I have this blog on a polish blog hosting service (blox.pl) that's incompatible with pretty much everything. There's two tools I can use to get data off it; one is to use a program that just simply won't work, and the other is to use another polish blog service (blog.pl), which is just wordpress, but it has a script that can import from blox.

Here's the kicker; now that I have the content on wordpress, blog.pl doesn't allow exports. I can't use the script either, since it's not available anywhere.

My question is this: does anyone have a script that parses a whole Wordpress blog and creates an useful .xml import file from it?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot install your own plugins you could set up a separate WordPress installation where you *can* do that and use the plugin [HTML Import 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/). From this site you can create a regular export file. You will not get all meta data (tags, categories etc.) though.